# Directly switch to NERDTree window

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Consider I have a NERDTree window and more then 2 file view windows are opened in vim. In this case a common way to switch to NERDTree (navigating with several Ctrl+w g/h/j/k) is not very handy as it is not universal for all the open windows.

Is there a way to switch to NERDTree (or any other, may be) window directly?

Comment: Your question would be better placed on [su].

Comment: Alternatively, I suggest you take a look at [Vimcast's Oil and vinegar - split windows and the project drawer](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/) article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your window layout, if NERDTree is near the top-left corner, it may have a fixed window number (`:echo winnr()` will tell you). You can then use `[N]<C-w><C-w>` to go to window number `[N]`.

If your layout is more dynamic, it might make sense to include the window number in your `'statusline'`:

```
:set statusline+=\ %{winnr()}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<C-w>t
```

should do what you want.

Comment: This one switches me to another window - top left (TagList panel, as I use Trinity plugin). May be there is a way to switch to a window by name?

Comment: Thanks for keeping an important information to yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a mapping to do this:

`nnoremap <silent> <Leader>t :NERDTreeFocus<CR>`